# jQuery slide down and slide up

Tags: jquery, html

I've table and I need to click rows. When I click on the rows, a div should slide down. this should happen for each row.

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="table_content">
    <tr id='a'>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id='b'>
       <td>4</td>
       <td>5</td>
       <td>6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So, when I click on any of the row, the following div should slide down.

```
<div>You slide down a row with content xyz</div>
```

This xyz is variable. For every row it is different. I'll be making an AJAX call for getting the `xyz`  value. For every row, it should slide down. The placement of the `<div>` should be just below the row. How can I do that?

Comment: Why downvote? Why is this offtopic? Please explain whosever have done that.

Comment: I guess that the downvote is for you not being able to deliver any test you've made, so it looks like a "I've-made-no-effort-please-solve-it" question. I guess.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a coding service, even though it often works as one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**slide toggle**](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fVz6D/)

**EDIT for displaying just Below the clicked Row**

```
tr {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}
.test {
    display:none;
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fVz6D/2/)

```
$('tr').click(function () {
    $(this).append(($('.test')).slideToggle('slow'));
})
```

HTML

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="table_content">
    <tr id='a'>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='b'>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div class="test">You slide down a row with content xyz</div>
```

Comment: *The placement of the <div> should be just below the row*

Comment: It slides down at the end of the table. Not in the middle of the row. How can I do that?

Comment: @user1162512 check the updated Fiddle Demo

Comment: There's a minor bug in this. If I click one row and then click another, both get slideUp().

Comment: Add `$('.test').slideUp(0)` in your jQuery. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. you [shouldn't use tables anymore](http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/index.html). You should use `display: inline-block` or `float: left` (note you will have to use one of the many clearfix methods if you choose to float)
2. Set it up like this

HTML

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="column">1</div>
   <div class="column">2</div>
   <div class="column">3</div>
   <div class="content">this is the content for a</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="column">1</div>
   <div class="column">2</div>
   <div class="column">3</div>
   <div class="content">this is the content for b</div>
<div>
```

CSS

```
.row{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

.column{
   display: inline-block;
}

.content{
   display: none;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$('.row').click(function(){
$(this).find('.content').slideToggle();
})
```

**UPDATE**: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jmore009/p5Apu/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't add a div, but another row, to integrate it in the table. Something like this should do:

```
$('tr').click(function() {
  $(this).after('<tr class="extra"><td colspan="3"><div>Your content is xyz</div></td></tr>');
  $(this).next('.extra').find('div').slideDown(500);
});
```

And some CSS

```
.extra div {
  display: none;
}
```

Haven't tested but that should do.

Comment: After testing a little bit, I've got to this solution, but is not really pretty. Is a good starting point, though. It's all yours!

http://jsfiddle.net/JK9wM/

Comment: Can you please post the solution here. The jsFiddle is not opening because of low-speed internet. Thanks